# What does it mean "To Teach The Young Idea How To Shoot"?

Tags: meaning

What does it mean "To Teach The Young Idea How To Shoot"?

This quote was taken from  ["Spring" by James Thomson:](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Spring_(Thomson))

> Then infant reason grows apace, and calls
>   For the kind hand of an assiduous care.
>   Delightful task! to rear the tender thought,
>   *To teach the young idea how to shoot,*
>   To pour the fresh instruction o'er the mind,
>   To breathe the enlivening spirit, and to fix
>   The generous purpose in the glowing breast.

Comment: Ok, I was going to give an answer but have only what I think. This line is taken from Spring, one of four parts of his poem called The Seasons, written in the 1730. It basically means teach young people how to grow up (shoot is like a plant's shoot, the shoot of a plant). When a plant produces shoots, it is growing. The grammar is kind of odd. It has zero to do with guns.

Comment: You would do better taking this to the Literature stack exchange. This is a poem from 1728. This is not a question about learning English, but about poetry.  I've included a link and the whole sentence from the poem, It appears to be about the joy of teaching.

Comment: Lambie's answer seems correct to me. Though the context is poetic, the less-used meaning of **shoot** is still in use in English today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a nice example of why learning English has some interesting challenges, and also gives and insight into why puns and similar wordplay occur so frequently in English conversation.

The word shoot has many different meanings, this dictionary has [seven different verb meanings](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/shoot), including making films, accelerating, and firing weapons.

It includes a meaning I'd not previously encountered: to grow or appear, as when branches produce a bud; this is to shoot. This surely is the meaning in the poem.

Comment: Little bit of information lacks but this answer will do just fine. :)